# Wordpress Admin extremely slow when other admin logged in

Tags: wp-admin, admin, performance

The sites has multiple authors/admins, who may sometimes edit/publish posts at the same time.

Whenever more than one user is author/administrator is editing/publishing another post, the WP Admin becomes extremely slow.

I can understand there may be additional some additional load in this scenario, however it is very noticeably slow just to load any page in the dashboard.

The site has 200-300 posts, and is in the green for all core web vitals. Heartbeat control is installed and set to 60.

It's also hosted using cPanel on a 4GB RAM KVM VPS (not shared with anyone else).

Anyone ever experience this?

Comment: core web vitals only measure frontend performance, not backend performance, they have no insight into what the server is doing, only its output. You will need to get more information than its slow, what is slow exactly? DB queries? HTTP requests? etc. Query Monitor may give you more useful information but this question isn't answerable at the moment. This isn't a discussion forum board, you need a specific question and be able to mark an answer as the factually correct answer for all people with this question (not just you).

Comment: You should try to disable all your plugins as well your mu-plugins and activate a default WP theme. Then activate each element, with performing a test between each activation to isolate the theme or plugins which slow down your back office. Once done, you would be able to contact their developers to know it's so slow. Regards

Comment: Thank you. @TomJNowell You're right. I should've at least used Query Monitor to get more information. Thanks for the guidance on how I should submit questions, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for the WordPress admin to become slow when multiple admins are logged in and editing or publishing posts at the same time. Here are a few Solutions you can try

- **Heartbeat API:** The Heartbeat API is a feature that allows WordPress
  to keep track of logged-in users and their activity. This can be a
  drain on resources, especially if multiple admins are logged in and
  actively using the dashboard.
- **Plugins:** Some plugins can also slow down the WordPress Admin
  dashboard. If you have a lot of plugins installed, it's worth
  disabling them one by one to see if one of them is causing the
  problem.
- **Database:** The WordPress database can also become slow if it's not
  properly optimized. You can use a plugin like WP-Optimize to optimize
  your database.